# Prevent network hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a network consisting of desktop computers, laptops and iPads. Internet is provided through MAC Address filtering.

Some users make the devices work as hotspot and use internet on their personal mobile phones. I want to prevent the unauthorized use.

Does it work when limiting the number of connections from a single IP Address ?

What can be done to prevent the hotspot sharing of the internet to unauthorized devices?